# How to add element by element of two STL vectors?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

The question is quite dumb, but I need to do it in a very efficient way - it will be performed over an over again in my code. I have a function that returns a vector, and I have to add the returned values to another vector, element by element. Quite simple:

```
vector<double> result;
vector<double> result_temp
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++) result_temp.push_back(i);

result += result_temp //I would like to do something like that.
for(int i =0; i< result_temp.size();i++)result[i] += result_temp[i]; //this give me segfault
```

The mathematical operation that I'm trying to do is

u[i] = u[i] + v[i] for all i

What can be done?

Thanks

EDIT: added a simple initialization, as that is not the point. How should result be initialized?

Comment: Would you post some compilable code?  "this gives me a segfault" is not particularly helpful without seeing how those vectors are initialized.  The most likely problem is that one of the vectors is longer than the other.  It's really hard to tell where your code is wrong without seeing all of the code :-)

Comment: I'm with @James McNellis - this code seems correct, as long as `result` and `result_temp` are the same length. Also - why did you declare `result`, but use the variable `result_v` - is that how the code is actually written? If so, that's an issue

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/operations_overview.htm

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you are trying to append one `vector` to another, you can use something like the following.  These are from one of my utilities libraries--two `operator+=` overloads for `std::vector`:  one appends a single element to the `vector`, the other appends an entire `vector`:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    a.insert(a.end(), b.begin(), b.end());
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& aVector, const T& aObject)
{
    aVector.push_back(aObject);
    return aVector;
}
```

If you are trying to perform a summation (that is, create a new `vector` containing the sums of the elements of two other `vector`s), you can use something like the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
std::vector<T> operator+(const std::vector<T>& a, const std::vector<T>& b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());

    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(a.size());

    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), 
                   std::back_inserter(result), std::plus<T>());
    return result;
}
```

You could similarly implement an `operator+=` overload.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not trying to append a value to the end of the vector, I'm trying to sum the existing value of the vector elements with the values of another vector. The size of the vectors are always fixed.

Comment: @Ivan:  See the edit; I was not entirely sure what you were looking for until I saw your comment in reply to Greg's answer.

Comment: @James Ignore my original comment - now you've got fancy AND relevant code :)

Comment: This looks great and is clean, but if efficiency is the main concern, I'd think that this would actually be slower than simply iterating over the elements and adding them together.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Jonathan:  It might be slower; I haven't profiled it or looked at the generated assembly.  If efficiency is a concern, a straightforward summation in a loop is probably the best option.

Comment: @Ivan:  Depending on what the compiler does to optimize this code, it may end up with far more function calls.  It depends.  If you profile your application and find that this solution is a bottleneck, then try to implement it differently.  For most applications, you'd never, ever notice the difference.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was slower than a manual loop. (Assuming you compile with optimizations enabled)

Answer (score 51):

It sure looks like the problem is accessing values of `result` that don't exist. tzaman shows how to initialize result to 10 elements, each with value 0.

Now you need to call the `transform` function (from <algorithm>), applying the `plus` function object (from <functional>):

```
std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result_temp.begin(),
               result.begin(), std::plus<double>());
```

This iterates over `result` and `result_temp`, applies `plus` that adds doubles, and writes the sum back to `result`.

Answer (score 13):

A concrete example of Jon Reid's answer:

```
std::array<double,3> a = {1, 2, 3};
std::array<double,3> b = {4, 5, 6};
std::transform(a.begin( ), a.end( ), b.begin( ), a.begin( ),std::plus<double>( ));
ASSERT_TRUE(a[0] == 5);
ASSERT_TRUE(a[1] == 7);
ASSERT_TRUE(a[2] == 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `result` to all zeros first; just declaring the variable doesn't actually allocate any elements.

Try this:

```
vector<double> result(10); // default-initialize to 10 elements
vector<double> result_temp;
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++) 
    result_temp.push_back(i);

for(int i =0; i< result_temp.size();i++)
    result[i] += result_temp[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is segfaulting then that's a correctness issue, not an efficiency issue.

To achieve "u[i] = u[i] + v[i] for all i", I would do basically what you did:

```
assert(u.size() == v.size()); // will fail with your initialization code, since
                              // your "result" has size 0, not size 10.
                              // perhaps do u.resize(v.size());
for (size_t i = 0; i < u.size(); ++i) {
    u[i] += v[i];
}
```

If you really care about performance of your program (that is, you've written a basic version and it's so slow that your program is failing some requirement, and you've proved that this is the code where much of the time is taken), then you could try:

- switching on lots of optimization in your compiler (actually, I usually do this by default even when there isn't a performance problem),
- using iterators instead of indexes (rarely makes much difference, but it's easy enough to compare the two),
- unrolling the loop a bit (can make a worthwhile speed difference, but that's quite sensitive to the particular case, and it encourages coding errors).
- looking at platform-specific SIMD instructions rather than C++. Then use embedded assembler or compiler intrinsics for those instructions.

Nevertheless, you have no business worrying about performance before your code is correct ;-). "Make it work, make it right, make it fast" is a reasonable motto, although often you don't need to go as far as step 3.

`std::valarray` actually has exactly the `operator+=` you want. Before you replace all your vectors with valarrays, be aware that doesn't necessarily mean it's any "more efficient" than a simple loop - I don't know how seriously implementers take `valarray`. You can always look at the source in your implementation. I also don't know why the multiple-data arithmetic functionality of `valarray` wasn't defined as part of `vector`, but there's usually a reason.

Answer (score -1):

The code seems fine, but my first inclination would be to alter whatever code is filling the vector with values to add to the values in the first vector to take in a reference to the first vector and add directly to it rather than creating a new vector that gets returned. That's just inefficient.

If you can't alter the function in that way, perhaps you can alter it so that it takes a reference to a vector which it clears and then inserts the values into so that you aren't copying vectors around. That can get to be expensive if you're doing it much.

Another nitpick if you're trying to get this as fast as possible, you should use pre-increment with iterators rather than post-increment. The temporary that post-increment creates can't be optimized away when dealing with overloaded operators rather than built-in types. So, you keep creating and destroying a temporary every iteration of your loop.  **EDIT:** As was pointed out in the comments, you're using indices here rather than iterators (I obviously wasn't paying enough attention), so this bit of advice doesn't really apply here. However, in cases where you *are* using iterators, it's still valid.

Other than that, if you're trying to add all of the elements of two vectors togther, what you have is probably about as efficient a solution as you're going to get. There are better ways if what you're concerned about is inserting the elements of one vector into another, but if you're just adding their values together, what you have looks good. I would expect that using any STL algorithms would be at best just as fast and likely slower due to extra function calls, but you'd probably have to profile it to be sure.

Comment: "you should use pre-increment with iterators rather than post-increment". True, but he's not using iterators, he's using an integer index. Hard to make a performance case between pre- and post-increment for that ;-)

Comment: Ah, good catch. I wasn't paying enough attention. I rarely used indices rather than iterators and my gut reaction to post-increment is very negative. I'm a firm believer in always using pre-increment unless you need post-increment. That way, you don't ever have to worry about whether the temporary will be optimized away. However, it is certainly true in this case that the compiler should have no problem optimizing it away and post-increment would be just as efficient as pre-increment.

Comment: Yes, even aside from possible performance issues I prefer pre-increment too, but for the controversial reason that I think it's more clear and readable. "Increment i" is spelled, "++ i". Few agree.