# Combining the values of two different sized vectors

Tags: c++, c++11

I was just wondering if there's a more readable way of combining the values of two vectors?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 7 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 19 };
    std::vector<int>::iterator v2it = v2.begin();

    if( v1.size() > v2.size() )
    {
        for( auto v1it = v1.begin(); v1it != v1.end(); ++v1it )
        {
            *v1it = *v1it + *v2it;
            std::cout << *v1it << std::endl;
            ++v2it;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        auto v1it = v1.begin();

        for( auto v2it = v2.begin(); v2it != v2.end(); ++v2it )
        {
            *v2it = *v2it + *v1it;
            std::cout << *v2it << std::endl;
            ++v1it;
        }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Output of above is:

2
4
6
12
19

Comment: **Your code is broken.** It makes as many iterations as the size of the *longer* vector. While doing it it attempts to access non-existing elements of the *shorter* vector. This is illegal. The question asks to "make it more readable", while in fact it is not clear what has to be done. It is impossible to derive it from broken code. State meaningfully what you are trying to do. How do you want to "combine" the value of vectors of different length?

Comment: OK, I thin there is the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376124/how-to-add-element-by-element-of-two-stl-vectors)

Comment: @AndyProwl Ugh, I got 3 CVs and still a downvote 'cause of my silly mistake :( People sure are quick to down vote & CV ;~;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::transform()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), which assumes ranges of the same length. I'll leave it up to you as an exercise to find out how to handle the case for ranges of different lengths:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 7 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 19 };

    std::transform(begin(v1), end(v1), begin(v2), 
                   std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "), std::plus<int>());
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/OsZXLZ).

Comment: +1 for std::plus, without any functors, lambdas, etc

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm just wondering why the question was closed so that I may improve it if it needs be =/

Comment: @maverik: and yet a loop to print the result instead of `std::copy(v1.begin(),v1.end(),std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," "));`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Shame on me, edited ;)

Comment: I actually believe you made it worse by merging the transform and the copy, since now it will only print `v1.size()` elements, not meeting the requirements :) [BTW, I don't necessarily mean that `std::ostream_iterator` is better/cleaner than the for loop, but given maverik's preference for not using a lambda it seemed to be in the line he expected]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That was the case even before ;) As the answer says, I left that part up to the reader

Comment: Oh, I did not realize... the opening question modifies in place of the larger of the two vectors and I did not quite read the code in your original version :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do mathematics with vectors you should take a look at [`std::valarray`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/)

Comment: hooray for remembering `valarray`!