# Dynamic Arrays: Add value of elements from two Dynamic Arrays in to new Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Hi I have vector A and vector B, each have 3 elements. I want to create a new vector which add the value of elements inside A and B.
i.e.

```
NewVector[0] = A[0] + B[0]
NewVector[1] = A[1] + B[1]
NewVector[2] = A[2] + B[2]
```

I need to do this command in one line, like NewVector = A + B; but it doesnt work. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add element by element of two STL vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376124/how-to-add-element-by-element-of-two-stl-vectors)

Comment: tl;dr Override the `operator+` for `std::vector`

Comment: Why one line? How unacceptable is one for statement with one line of addition?

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::transform` in `<algorithm>` library. It "maps" collection(s) into another by functor that passed in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    for (auto& el : vec)
    {
        os << el << ' ';
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {1,10,100};
    std::vector<int> b {2,20,200};
    std::vector<int> c {};

    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c), std::plus<int>());

    //Or you can use C++11 lambda:
    //std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), std::back_inserter(c), [](int x, int y){return x+y;});

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3 30 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is even shorter version of what texasbruce already posted:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> b = {100,200,300};
    std::vector<int> c;
    std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), back_inserter(c), [](int x, int y) {return x + y;});
    std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), [](int x) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is exactly the same. The cout part is just the code from `coliru`