# subtract integer vectors in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

if  I have

```
vector <int>taw1 , vector<int>taw2;
```

and I want to calculate

```
vector<int>delta =taw2-taw1;
```

how the subtraction can be done ?

Comment: Have you considered to look into the documentation of the vector class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add element by element of two STL vectors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376124/how-to-add-element-by-element-of-two-stl-vectors)

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like

```
Mat mdelta = Mat(taw2) - Mat(taw1);
mdelta.copyTo(delta);
```

as seen on the test code:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    vector<int> taw1;
    vector<int> taw2;
    vector<int> delta;

    for( int i =1; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        taw1.push_back( i );
        taw2.push_back( i*3 );
    }

    Mat mdelta = Mat(taw2) - Mat(taw1);
    mdelta.copyTo(delta);

    cout << "taw1\n" << Mat(taw2) << endl;
    cout << "taw2\n" << Mat(taw1) << endl;
    cout << "taw2 - taw1\n" << Mat(delta) << endl;
    cout << "taw2 + taw1\n" << Mat(taw2) + Mat(taw1) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ,the values of taw1 and taw2 are integers I don't want to convert them to Mat .    is                                                                                       Mat mdelta = Mat(taw2) - Mat(taw1);                                                        converting them to Mat ?

Comment: No conversion here, just creating Mat header.

Comment: Why creating Mat header ? Sorry for my question I just started learning opencv