# Adding four vectors c++ using std::transform()

Tags: c++, std, ubuntu-18.04

I have a problem adding four vectors using `std::transform`. It sounds like a simple problem, but I couldn't get it done. Suppose I have the following:

`std::vector<double> No_of_sgn1, No_of_sgn2, No_of_sgn3, No_of_sgn4;`

Each one of these vectors having 4 elements (double). So I tried to add only two vectors as:

`std::transform(No_of_sgn1.begin(), No_of_sgn1.end(), No_of_sgn2.begin(), No_of_sgn1.begin(), std::plus<double>());`

I assume that the `No_of_sgn2` will be added to `No_of_sgn1`, then I print to see what is the result:

`std::cout << No_of_sgn1[0] << std::endl;`

However, the code breaks here giving me:

> *** Break *** segmentation violation

```
    TString getlabel(TString fileName, bool nu = false){

 TString g = "";

  if(fileName.Contains("345060"))       g = "ggH";
  if(fileName.Contains("344235"))       g = "VBF";
  if(fileName.Contains("AZNLO_VH"))     g = "VH";
  if(fileName.Contains("ttH125_ZZ4l"))  g = "ttH";
  if(fileName.Contains("Zjet"))         g = "Z+jets";
  if(fileName.Contains("A14_ttbar"))    g = "tt";


 return g;
}

TString getbinName(int xBin,TString type);
map<TString, std::map<int, double>> val;

    int main(){
//this part contains the place where the data imported
TChain *chain = new TChain("tree_relaxIsoD0");

chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16_13TeV.345060.PowhegPythia8EvtGen_NNLOPS_nnlo_30_ggH125_ZZ4l_bkgCR.root");               //ggH
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16_13TeV.344235.PowhegPy8EG_NNPDF30_AZNLOCTEQ6L1_VBFH125_ZZ4lep_notau_bkgCR.root");        //VBF
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16a_13TeV.PowhegPythia8EvtGen_NNPDF30_AZNLO_VH_MINLO_bkgCR_merged_3s.root");  //VH
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16a_13TeV.PowhegPy8EG_A14NNPDF23_NNPDF30ME_ttH125_ZZ4l_allhad_merged_3s.root");            //ttH
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/BkgCR/mc16_13TeV.Sherpa_NNPDF30NNLO_Zjet_bkgCR_merged_4s.root"); //Z+jets
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/BkgCR/mc16_13TeV.410289.PhPy8EG_A14_ttbar_hdamp258p75_4lMFilt_40_8_bkgCR.root");                    //ttbar


Histos a(chain);
a.Loop();

return 0;
}

for(int j=2; j<6;j++){
    if(groupName=="ggH" ) No_of_sgn1.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
    if(groupName=="VBF" ) No_of_sgn2.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
    if(groupName=="VH" ) No_of_sgn3.push_back(val[groupName][j]); 
    if(groupName=="ttH" ) No_of_sgn4.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
    if(groupName=="Z+jets") No_of_bkg1.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
    if(groupName=="tt" ) No_of_bkg2.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
 }
```

it was something like the above.
Up to here everything is fine. I even printed out the values of all the vectors, and they look quite right. This is how I print the first vector:

```
 "if(groupName=="ggH") cout<<groupName<<":"<<" 4mu: "<<No_of_sgn1[0]<<" 4e: "<<No_of_sgn1[1]<<" 2mu2e: "<<No_of_sgn1[2]<<" 2e2mu: "<<No_of_sgn1[3]<<endl; ".
```

And the output is:

> "ggH: 4mu: 0.869109 4e: 0.452978 2mu2e: 0.485973 2e2mu: 0.605595

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376124/how-to-add-element-by-element-of-two-stl-vectors
Try the following code and see what happens
```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
int main ()
{
    std::vector<double> vec1 = {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4};
    std::vector<double> vec2 = {0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8};
    std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec1.begin(), std::plus<double>());
    std::cout << vec1[0] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did actually. And I have all the include that you pointed out in my code. Perhaps the problem is the way that I store the elements of the vectors!

Comment: You did not show how you initialized your vectors and so it's difficult to help you to fully understand why your code would be segfaulting. This is why we request askers to include an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so that we can be as helpful as possible. If you edit your post to include the MCVE code snippet, we can certainly help.

Comment: for(int j=2; j<6;j++){

   if(groupName=="ggH"   ) No_of_sgn1.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
   if(groupName=="VBF"   ) No_of_sgn2.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
   if(groupName=="VH"    ) No_of_sgn3.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
   if(groupName=="ttH"   ) No_of_sgn4.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
   if(groupName=="Z+jets") No_of_bkg1.push_back(val[groupName][j]);
   if(groupName=="tt"    ) No_of_bkg2.push_back(val[groupName][j]);

}
Sorry for that, it was something like the above.

Comment: Up to here everything is fine. I even printed out the values of all the vectors, and they look quite right. This is how I print the first vector "if(groupName=="ggH") cout<<groupName<<":"<<" 4mu: "<<No_of_sgn1[0]<<" 4e: "<<No_of_sgn1[1]<<" 2mu2e: "<<No_of_sgn1[2]<<" 2e2mu:  "<<No_of_sgn1[3]<<endl;
". And the out put is "ggH: 4mu: 0.869109 4e: 0.452978 2mu2e: 0.485973 2e2mu:  0.605595".

Comment: The additional code is still incomplete since `val` and `groupName` are not previously defined. Try to include everything necessary for someone here to compile out-of-the-box, but *filter* out anything that is not directly relevant to the question (e.g. if your `val` structure is populated by a database call, we don't need to know that, just need it to be initialized somehow relevantly). Also, have you put this through a debugger (gdb)? This can give you a backtrace usually of the error(s) and you can have the program pause anywhere, show you memory/values on the stack, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I will try to include most of the necessary code here. 

TString getlabel(TString fileName, bool nu = false){
 TString g = ""; 
  if(fileName.Contains("345060"))        g = "ggH";
  if(fileName.Contains("344235"))        g  = "VBF";
  if(fileName.Contains("AZNLO_VH")) g = "VH";
  if(fileName.Contains("ttH125_ZZ4l"))g = "ttH";
  if(fileName.Contains("Zjet"))              g = "Z+jets";
  if(fileName.Contains("A14_ttbar"))     g = "tt";
 return g;
}

TString getbinName(int xBin,TString type);
map<TString, std::map<int, double>> val;

Comment: //Here where all the data go, but the files are hugh. 
int main(){
TChain *chain = new TChain("tree_relaxIsoD0");

chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16_13TeV.345060.PowhegPythia8EvtGen_NNLOPS_nnlo_30_ggH125_ZZ4l_bkgCR.root");               //ggH
chain->Add("~/cernbox/Lepron_Isolation/samples/Prod_v18/mc16a/Signal/mc16_13TeV.344235.PowhegPy8EG_NNPDF30_AZNLOCTEQ6L1_VBFH125_ZZ4lep_notau_bkgCR.root");        //VBF

Histos a(chain);
a.Loop();

return 0;
}

void Histos::Loop()
{

Comment: I'm really sorry! the code is just too long and I can type it here. Is there any way to attach files?

Comment: Does `No_of_sgn2` have enough elements?

Comment: Yes, it has enough elements. I checked this by printing out all the elements of each vector after storing them.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot, everyone. I happened to solve the problem. First, I converted all the vectors into arrays as below:

```
double s1[3]; double s2[3]; double s3[3]; double s4[3];
double b1[3]; double b2[3];

std::copy(No_of_sgn1.begin(), No_of_sgn1.end(), s1);
std::copy(No_of_sgn2.begin(), No_of_sgn2.end(), s2);
std::copy(No_of_sgn3.begin(), No_of_sgn3.end(), s3);
std::copy(No_of_sgn4.begin(), No_of_sgn4.end(), s4);
std::copy(No_of_bkg1.begin(), No_of_bkg1.end(), b1);
std::copy(No_of_bkg2.begin(), No_of_bkg2.end(), b2);
```

Then I did the following:

```
double No_of_sgn[3];
double No_of_bkg[3];

for(int g=0; g<4;g++){
  No_of_sgn[g] =  s1[g]+s2[g]+s3[g]+s4[g];
  No_of_bkg[g] =  b1[g]+b2[g];
}

cout<<" 4mu: "<<No_of_sgn[0]<<" 4e: "<<No_of_sgn[1]<<" 2mu2e: "<<No_of_sgn[2]<<" 2e2mu: "<<No_of_sgn[3]<<endl;
```

The output of the cout is:

```
4mu: 18.9752 4e: 9.90788 2mu2e: 10.5984 2e2mu: 13.2445
```

Which is what I wanted :)

Cheers,

Abdualazem.